# Generate Graph in Web Browser or Java?

Tags: java, swing, graph, linegraph

How do I generate graph (line graph, bar graph) in front end either in web browser or in Java Swing ?

Comment: These are two wildly different questions with wildly different answers. I suggest you refine your question and decide what you're trying to do.

Do you have a swing app? Do you have a web app? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is an open source java library. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Answer (score 0):

You can use JFreeChart which comes as an addon with Jasper Reports. Jasper Reports will facilitate you to build reports,charts,graphs etc and display them easily on your user interface. Use iReports to build report template easily for JasperReporting. The entire process requires you to write only a few lines of code..